# Applying log on a column read from file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, external-files

I'm trying to plot some data from a file and I want to apply the natural log on the values from one column.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
     \addplot+ table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\ln{\thisrowno{1}}]{data.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So the problem is in this part (i.e. how to apply ln() on one column):

```
y expr=\ln{\thisrowno{1}}
```

I've also tried with \log{}. The pgfplots manual isn't very talkative on this either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you provide a sample `data.txt`?

Comment: With a `data.txt` I could test, but I'm 99% sure it should be `y expr=ln(\thisrowno{1})`.

Comment: @PaulGessler Makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `y expr=ln(\thisrowno{1})` (note parentheses and no backslash with `ln`).

The parentheses are standard usage for the `pgf` math functions (e.g. `sin(x)`, `cos(x)`). Inside key-value expressions, curly braces are only used to protect certain contents and to delimit macro arguments. By the same token `\ln`, `\sin`, `\cos`, etc. are used (in math mode) when we want to *typeset* that function. For *computing* the function using the `pgfmath` engine, the backslash is left off.

Here's the full sample code (I created my own simple data file):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{datapaul.txt}
 1 1
 2 2
 3 3
 4 4
 5 5
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
     \addplot+ table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=ln(\thisrowno{1})]{datapaul.txt};
     \addplot {ln(x)}; % just for test
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An `expl3`-based answer, because that's what I was working on.  I'm not too familiar with PGF :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
 1 1
 2 2
 3 3
 4 4
 5 5
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_nopar:Npn \NaturalLog #1
 { \fp_eval:n { ln (#1) } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
     \addplot+ table [x expr=\thisrowno{0}, y expr=\NaturalLog{\thisrowno{1}}]{data.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The pure PGF answer should be preferred, but this answer may be useful for more complex operations where `expl3` is already being used. I'm not sure which calculation engine is faster.